# What could have damaged my git repo?

Tags: git

Today I started to work on a project of mine, but git seemed to have "forgotten" about the repository. Any git command (except `init` and alike) would have resulted in:
`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

However I was in a directory where `.git` existed. After googling a while I found out that git needs a file called `HEAD` which is a pointer to the "HEAD". However this file was missing. I also found out that ORIG_HEAD, which I did have should point to an older "HEAD".

I tried to do `cp ORIG_HEAD HEAD`, which made git realize that it is an repository, but:

```
$ git status

fatal: unable to read tree 9d1dcfdaf1a6857c5f83dc27019c7600e1ffaff8


$ git log
commit ab071ed2e391f0d8e7f0e3d3a7f86735fe3947b9
Author: Esa Varemo <esa@kuivanto.fi>
Date:   Fri Jul 19 19:00:05 2013 +0300

    Added a template config file


< a few commits cut out>    


error: Could not read 5af6cdcf9387971ef52fdc0d00550fbc49d325c2
fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 948dd8ba52a36f780d58d38f7e1e083a277cbfe7
```

A few days ago when I last worked on it there were no problems. I changed a few files, committed the changes and pushed to a remote repo (so I do have a backup).

Any ideas what could have happened?

Comment: what is the file system you are using?

Comment: @fotanus The fs is ext4. I'll propably do a fsck, but it will be about a week until I can access the physical box...

Comment: I think I should also mention that I just remembered that the project is synced by dropbox, so it could be caused by some dropboxd bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HEAD file needs to point to a branch NOT a commit. If you know the name of the branch you are working on try this:

HEAD file

```
ref: refs/heads/branch_name_here
```

You may have to dig around your .git/refs/heads folder. The files in there should have the branchname as their file name, with the latest commit in that branch as the ONLY content.

Good luck!

Comment: That fixed the problem, and it seems normal again. The ORIG_HEAD seems to be from when I accidentally worked on a detached HEAD, and merged it back to master. Now the question is where the "new" HEAD disappeared

Comment: I'm still thinking about it :) When the question was "What broke it?" and not "How to fix it?". However I greatly appreciate your help and unless somebody comes up with a good answer to the original question, I might accept this

Comment: Ah, no worries. Good point, leave it open, you've got me intrigued too!

Comment: Two minor footnotes: a HEAD that's not a symbolic `ref:` thing is a "detached head" [footnote to footnote: in very old versions of git, instead of the text "ref: ..." git used a symlink for a symbolic ref!], and, sometimes commit IDs will be in a "packed" refs file, `.git/packed-refs`, rather than separate files in `.git/refs/heads/`.